# Delete task is not working under Context Menu?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I was developing Windows Phone App using this sample: [Local Database Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Local-Database-Sample-57b1614c)

In that sample, Delete Task has been implemented using an icon. I have modified Delete Task by `Context Menu`. But, it does not works for me.

If I pressed `Delete`, nothing happens.

I dunno what mistake I have done.

**My modified Code:**

**XAML Code:**

```
<TextBlock 
    Text="{Binding ItemName}" 
    FontWeight="Thin" FontSize="28" 
    Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top">

    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
    <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="ContextMenu">
    <toolkit:MenuItem Name="Delete"  Header="Delete" Click="deleteTaskButton_Click"/>
    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>

</TextBlock>
```

**C# Code:**

```
private void deleteTaskButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Cast the parameter as a button.
        var button = sender as TextBlock;

        if (button != null)
        {
            // Get a handle for the to-do item bound to the button.
            ToDoItem toDoForDelete = button.DataContext as ToDoItem;
            App.ViewModel.DeleteToDoItem(toDoForDelete);
            MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully");
        }

        // Put the focus back to the main page.
        this.Focus();
    }
```

**Working original Code in that sample:**

**XAML Code:**

```
<TextBlock 
    Text="{Binding ItemName}" 
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" 
    Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="-36, 12, 0, 0"/>
<Button                                
    Grid.Column="3"
    x:Name="deleteTaskButton"
    BorderThickness="0"
    Margin="0, -18, 0, 0"
    Click="deleteTaskButton_Click">
<Image 
    Source="/Images/appbar.delete.rest.png"
    Height="75"
    Width="75"/>
</Button>
```

**C# Code:**

```
private void deleteTaskButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Cast the parameter as a button.
        var button = sender as Button;

        if (button != null)
        {
            // Get a handle for the to-do item bound to the button.
            ToDoItem toDoForDelete = button.DataContext as ToDoItem;

            App.ViewModel.DeleteToDoItem(toDoForDelete);

            MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully");
        }

        // Put the focus back to the main page.
        this.Focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `sender` is not a `TextBlock`, so this line:

```
var button = sender as TextBlock;
```

returns `null`

You can cast it to `MenuItem`.

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
....

private void deleteTaskButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    var item = sender as MenuItem;

    if (item!= null)
    {
        // Get a handle for the to-do item bound to the button.
        ToDoItem toDoForDelete = item .DataContext as ToDoItem;
        App.ViewModel.DeleteToDoItem(toDoForDelete);
        MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully");
    }

    // Put the focus back to the main page.
    this.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Error: `The name 'button' does not exist in the current context`